# Role of methane in global warming

Tags: atmospheric-science, climate-science, chemical-compounds

I am a young student in physic and I am doing a little presentation on how does climate change works. So I went on the wikipedia page for greenhouse gases.
[image]
I don't understant why methane is more dangerous for the climate change than carbon dioxyde because the rays that methane absorbe are the same as water vapor, and water vapor absorbe it more. So I don't understand why methane play such a role.
If someone have an answer I would be very grateful

Comment: There are several reasons that I think this is scare mongering:  1) methane is a very flammable gas, so it can't build up to more than a minuscule concentration in the atmosphere, which contains 21% oxygen;  2) as you pointed out, other greenhouse gases are absorbing IR in the same range as methane;  3) there are MANY natural processes (e.g., swamps) that are emitting methane all the time, and those natural processes cannot be stopped from emitting methane.  Despite that, the methane concentration in the atmosphere is NOT building up.

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Atmospheric_Transmission.png

Comment: DavidWhite, you think that the main reason it is dangerous is that methane burn in the atmosphere and thus create CO2 ?

Comment: [Taux of methane in the atmosphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DA9jY.gif). The taux of methane is buling up no ?

Comment: There's some relevant info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_methane

Comment: @tom10 I suppose it's transmittance of the atmosphere from ground level to the "top of atmosphere".

Comment: @Ruslan: So when it goes above 100% that means what exactly?

Comment: @tom10 Where did you spot such an overshoot? The only chart with explicit percentage scale ends at 100%.

Comment: @Ruslan: I see now! My bad. These are absorption curves, not transmission. That is, when the dark fill goes to 100%, that means the wavelength is totally absorbed. And, of course the transmission graph is flipped. What I was expecting was a normal transmittance-like curve, which is curved leading into the regions where the transmission is high and bumpy along the top (that is, 100% transmission is less easy than 100% absorption). And it says absorption in the title, which should have been a clue.

Comment: @TimothéeTremblais, did you actually read the plot of methane concentration that you published?  It shows methane leveling off at approximately 1800 parts per BILLION.  Concentration matters, and this is a VERY low concentration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I give my answer, I need to comment on two points above.

First, contrary to a comment made above, methane IS building up in the atmosphere, just not at a large rate.  See figure 2 [here](https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/aggi/aggi.html) from NOAA.

Second, contrary to the OP's statement, methane absorption bands do not significantly overlap those of water.  Go to [this](https://explainingclimatechange.com/lesson6/6_3_1.html) website and click on the "IR Windows Learning Tool".  In that window you can overlay water and CH4 and see what I mean.

I've been interested in the science behind climate change for a few years, but a simple answer to your question is not easily found, as I found out in trying to compose this response.  So - **good question**!

Now it is well-known that the change in radiative forcing, $\Delta F$, for CO2 is roughly logarithmic: $$\Delta F=5.35ln{\frac{C}{C_0}}$$  You can see this formula in table 1 from the NOAA link I gave above.  Here $C_0$ is the reference concentration and C is the concentration of interest.  Thus folks like to say that every doubling of CO2 in the atmosphere gives the same change in radiative forcing.  The reason behind this logarithmic behavior is not [straight-forward](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/2014JD022466).  Though the paper referenced here presents a specific model of the atmosphere to obtain this logarithmic dependence, it is plain the model contains such features as **absorber concentration** and **absorption cross-section** which play a role in the optical depth, $\tau$.

As seen also in table 1 from the NOAA reference, the change in radiative forcing for CH4 is more dependent on the difference in the square root of the concentration of interest relative to the reference concentration.  From what I can gather, this is a distinction without much of a difference as they are both less than linear.  It would be assumed also that, as with CO2, absorber concentration and absorption cross-section play similar roles in the mathematical form here as well.

Currently the amount of CO2 in the atmosphere is around 410 ppm, while that of CH4 is around 1.8 ppm.  Thus, relatively speaking, it takes very little change in CH4 to double its change in radiative forcing as compared to CO2.  Thus, the change in radiative forcing can climb very quickly for CH4.

The IPCC have developed the concept of "Global Warming Potential (GWP)", which tries to compare the strength of a well-mixed green house gas with that of CO2 (technically it compares a pulse into the atmosphere of the gas in question with a pulse of equal mass of CO2).  The concept is discussed technically in AR5, Chapter 8, pages [710-712](https://www.ipcc.ch/site/assets/uploads/2018/02/WG1AR5_Chapter08_FINAL.pdf).  As with many climate concepts, this one can be troublesome if you don't understand what it leaves out, and I am certainly no expert here.  The first paragraph on page 711 is good reading on this point.

The take-home point of GWP with respect to CH4 is the black curve in figure 8.29, reproduced below.  There we see the off-quoted number that over a 100 year span, the GWP of CH4 is roughly 28x that of CO2.

I know this was probably not the simple answer you were looking for, but I hope this provides some help.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot it solves my problem and you gave me a lot to read so it will help me more than I hoped in the first place.

Comment: Hi @TimothéeTremblais .  Glad you found it useful!

Comment: I went on the website you gave me to see the absorbtion wavelength of differents green house gases but I still don't understand why methane play such a role. If you look at this [graph](https://postimg.cc/ThdDggxM) you can see that CO2 absorbe way more than methane and absorbes right in the middle of the emmission spectra of black body when methane is absorbing on the side of the spectrum. (pardon my english I'm french...)

Comment: Hi @TimothéeTremblais .  The best I can tell you here is that at its present low level, if methane begins to rise, it can easily increase its radiative forcing due to the equation referenced above.  If you look at a ln plot or a square root function, you will see that these functions have a very steep slope at the start - so there is a big change Y for a small X change - relatively speaking, of course.  So while it is correct that CO2 sits at a better spot than CH4, most of that band is already used, while very little of the CH4 band is used.